# NameValueCollection doesn't actually do anything with its IEqualityComparer?

Tags: iequalitycomparer, namevaluecollection

I am looking at `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection` and it takes an `IEqualityComparer`, which is good news if someone like me wanted to sort the items in the collection by, say, something like the alphabetical order of the keys.

But, on a closer look in `Reflector`, I don't see the `NVC` class actually using the `IEqualityComparer` anywhere. Is my observation correct? As in, I don't see any use for an `IEqualityComparer` in an enumerable entity other than to re-arrange its constituent items on some cardinal order. And I do not see a method on `NVC` that looks like it might want to do something of that sort (`Sort`, `Arrange`, `OrderBy`, `Aggregate`, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NameValueCollection` uses a [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) internally to store the values. The `Hashtable` uses the `IEqualityComparer` to hash and compare keys for equality.

Also note that `IEqualityComparer` doesn't do any ordering, it only compares for equality (as the name implies) so it's not useful if you want to *sort* values/keys.